# how to save android studio stacktrace Logs into text file in device internal Storage

Tags: java, android, kotlin, logging, text

Is it possible to  Save Android Studio stack trace log into text file in device storage for tracing error and bugs in real device ?
I want save All Android Studio logs into text programmatically.

How can i implement locally logging system in android Application.

Comment: Your question is abit unclear .Are you refering to an android applications logs stacktrace or the actual Android studio applications logs?

Comment: Do you only want traces from crashes?

Comment: Not only creashes but i want to save all logs save into logs file that file create in device internal storage .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

First implement a crash reported for your app, when ever you need to save stack trace, manually create a division by zero crash. When you start your app again, stack trace is available for you. Here the crash reporter displays a dialog and ask user to email the stack trace, you can save it to a file instead of displaying the dialog!

Here is a full explanation for setup your own crash reporter, it will show a dialog like this to the user when your app starts again and asks him/her to send the log with email:

[image]

1- Create a class names UnexpectedCrashSaver:

```
public class UnexpectedCrashSaver implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;
private Context app = null;
public UnexpectedCrashSaver(Context app) {
    this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    this.app = app;
}
public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    StackTraceElement[] arr = e.getStackTrace();
    String report = e.toString()+"\n\n";
    report += "--------- Stack trace ---------\n\n";
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        report += "    "+arr[i].toString()+"\n";
    }
    report += "-------------------------------\n\n";
    App.instance().toastShort("saving!");

    report += "--------- Cause ---------\n\n";
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    if(cause != null) {
        report += cause.toString() + "\n\n";
        arr = cause.getStackTrace();
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            report += "    "+arr[i].toString()+"\n";
        }
    }
    report += "-------------------------------\n\n";
    try {
        FileOutputStream trace = app.openFileOutput("stack.trace",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        trace.write(report.getBytes());
        trace.close();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        // ...
    }
    defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);
}
}
```

2- Add this line to your onCreate() method of Application class:

```
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnexpectedCrashSaver(this));
```

if you don't have application class add this code to your onCreate() method of all activities: (if you have BaseActivity just put it in onCreate() method of BaseActivity

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnexpectedCrashSaver(ActivityName.this));
```

3- create a layout named checkbox.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

4- Add the following method to your MainActivity class:

```
 private void checkForCrash()
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean crash_never_ask_again = preferences.getBoolean("crash_never_ask_again", false);
    if(crash_never_ask_again)//Previously user check the checkbox of never ask me again about sending crash dialog
        return;
    String dialog_message = "In the last run, the program encountered an error, we apologize for this, you can kindly send us the error information to fix this error in future updates.";
    String button_positive_text = "Send";
    String button_negative_text = "Close";
    String checkbox_text = "Never ask again";
    String email = "crashreport@example.com";

    String line;
    String trace="";
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(MainActivity.this.openFileInput("stack.trace")));
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            trace += line+"\n";
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        // ...
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        // ...
    }
    if(trace.length() < 10)//We didn't have any crash
        return;

    View checkBoxView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.checkbox, null);
    CheckBox checkBox =  checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("checkbox_checked",true);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
    checkBox.setText(checkbox_text);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    //builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_setting);
    builder.setMessage(dialog_message);
    builder.setView(checkBoxView);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    String finalTrace = trace;
    builder.setPositiveButton(button_positive_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            String subject = "Error report";
            String body = "Mail this to appdeveloper@gmail.com: " + "\n" + finalTrace + "\n";

            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {email});
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Title:"));
            MainActivity.this.deleteFile("stack.trace");
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(button_negative_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            MainActivity.this.deleteFile("stack.trace");
            boolean checkbox_checked = preferences.getBoolean("checkbox_checked", false);
            if(checkbox_checked)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("crash_never_ask_again",true);
                editor.apply();
            }
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

5- call the method created in step 4 in onCreate method of MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    checkForCrash();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //...
```

Thats all!